# Tkinter doesnt want to update

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a counter that when reaching threshpoints is suposed to do stuff (add colors) but even tho the append functions shows that it works in printing the aditional color isnt used.

```
import tkinter
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(height=500,width=500)
canvas.pack()
import random


new_thing = 0
def block(pl):
    global new_thing
    color = ["pink","blue","red"]
    x = pl.x
    y = pl.y
    canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x+15,y+15,fill=random.choice(color))
    new_thing += 1
    if new_thing == 10:
        color.append("green")
        print(color)
        print("yay new color")
    print(new_thing)

canvas.bind("<Button-1>",block)
```

Answer (score 0):

The list `color` is a local variable of the function `block` and gets initialized to its default value `["pink","blue","red"]` every time the function is called, hence your `append` command is just redundant and will have no effect.

What you can do is to move the `color` variable to the global space and then append the value, your final code should look like this.

```py
import tkinter
import random

root=tkinter.Tk()

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root,height=500,width=500)
canvas.pack()

new_thing = 0
def block(pl):
    global new_thing
    x = pl.x
    y = pl.y
    canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x+15,y+15,fill=random.choice(color))
    new_thing += 1
    if new_thing == 10:
        color.append("green")
        print(color)
        print("yay new color")
    print(new_thing)

canvas.bind("<Button-1>",block)
color = ["pink","blue","red"]

root.mainloop()
```

Note that I have made a few other changes to the code, they are just to make it easily reproducible.